# Why can't backbone find HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I am building a file library view for a web app I am building at the moment, the basics behind the app is that,

- There is a project.
- Each project can be split in to multiple items
- A user can upload a file to an item or a project
- If the file is uploaded it is shown both in the projects library & the items library

The current problem I am having is that I can view the the projects file library fine. There a no problems and here is the code that I am using,

**Load File View**

```
loadFileView: function() {
    var fileView = new app.ProjectFilesView({
        collection:app.FileList
    });
    this.$el.find('#files').html(fileView.render().el);
    fileView.addRepo();
},
```

**Projects File View**

```
render: function() {

    this.$el.html(this.template({

        fileDetails: this.collection,
        p: app.project.toJSON()

    }));

    console.log(this.collection)

    return this;
},

addRepo: function(filter) {

    var repoView = new app.ProjectFilesRepoView;

    this.$el.parents("#files").find('.file_content:first').append(repoView.render().el);

},
```

**Create the FilePanelWrapperView**

```
new app.FilePanelWrapperView({
    collection : app.FileList
});
```

This is section of code is what actually build the library (display in a grid format).

```
initialize: function() {
    //this.model.on('change', this.updateVisibility, this);
    this.addFiles();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.updateCounter);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addNewOne);

 },

 addFiles: function() {
      //this.$('ul.share').html('');
  this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
 },

 addOne: function( file ) {

    var view = new app.FilePanelView({
        model: file
    });

    view.render().el;

    var expander = $('article.project_files').find('span.expander').length;

    if (expander == 0) {

        $('article.project_files header h1').prepend('<span class="expander"></span>');
        //bind the expander
        $('.expander').unbind('click').click($.initExpanders.expander);
    //$('.file_content').show();

    }
},
```

**Render the item**

```
renderItem: function() {

    //console.log(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    $("body .tab-content.files ul.image-grid").prepend(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    this.$el.find(".thumb-panel-container").tipTip({
        delay: 0,
        defaultPosition: "top"
    }).hover(function() {
        $(this).children(".thumb-panel-menu").fadeIn(100);
    ;
    },function () {
        $(this).children(".thumb-panel-menu").fadeOut(100)
    ;
    });

    $("time").timeago();

    return this;
}
```

Now for the item library I am pretty much doing the same code, but looking to apply it to a different element `.tab-content.files .image-grid` which is there on page load, but backbone cant seem to find it why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So you're saying that `$("body .tab-content.files ul.image-grid")` isn't finding anything when you're certain that it should?

Comment: If I console.log that it will find but if I then console.log it renderItem function it returns nothing.

Comment: So it you look for `body .tab-content.files ul.image-grid` inside `renderItem`, it isn't there but if you look for it later, it is there? Modifying things outside your `this.el` is generally a bad idea. And mixing that sort of `prepend` call with `this.$el.find` is bizarre. Doing `this.$el.parents` is also rather bizarre. I suspect that you have some structural and encapsulation problems in your app.

Comment: Like @muistooshort said above, altering the page from a view is not recommended at all. Why not have that external container `body .tab-content.files ul.image-grid` as an independent view that listens to the same collection, or if you want to keep it decoupled, use events to notify the external view that it should be updated? You can create a global event handler (also know as [mediator](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript)) by using the Backbone object itself or by cloning Backbone.Events `var mediator = _.clone(Backbone.Events)`;